# Algorithm/Hashing/Creative Way To Map Beyond 2 Alphanumeric Characters Combinations

Tags: algorithm, hash, mapping

I have a system that is confined to two alphanumeric characters. Some simple math shows that we get 1,296 combinations if we use all possible permutations 0-9 and a-z. Lower case letters cannot be distinguished from upper case, special characters (including a blank character) cannot be used.

Is there any creative mapping, perhaps to an external reference, to create a way to take this two character field significantly beyond 1,296 combinations?

Examples of identifers would be `00, OO, AZ, Z4, etc.'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not, no more than you could get a 3 bit number to represent more than 8 different numbers.  If you're interested in the details you can look up information theory or [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).  Essentially with only 1,296 combinations then you can only label 1,296 possible pieces of information.

As an example, consider if you had 1,297 things.  All of those two letter combinations would take up the first 1,296 so what combination would be associated with the next one?  It would have to be a repeat of something which you had earlier.

Shor also has some good material on this, and the implications of that sort of thing form the basis for a lot of file compression systems.

You could *maybe* squeeze out one more combination if you cheat, and allow a 'null' value to represent a different possibility, but thats not totally relevant to the idea of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are restricted to two characters taken from an alphabet of 36, then you are limited to 36² distinct symbols, that's it.

More context is required to find workarounds, like stealing bits elsewhere, using symbols in pairs, breaking the case limitation, exploiting the history of transations...

Answer (score 0):

The precise meaning of "a system that is confined to two alphanumeric characters" needs to be known to be able to suggest a workaround. Is that a space constraint? Do you need the restriction to 2 chars for efficiency? Does it need to work with other code that accepts or generates 2 char indexes?

If you have up to 1295 identifiers that are used often, and some others that occur only occasionally, you could choose an identifier, e.g. "ZZ", to indicate that another identifier is following. So "00" through to "ZY" would be 1295 simple 2-char identifiers, and "ZZ00" though to "ZZZZ" would be a further 1296 combined 4-char identifiers. (Or "ZZ0000" through to "ZZZZZZ" for a further 1296*1296 identifiers ...)

This could work for space constraints. For efficiency, it depends on whether the additional check to see if the identifier is "ZZ" is too expensive or not.